# bytes array into a char in VBA

Tags: char, byte

Char  (as an example) in UTF 8 consists of four bytes: 240, 145, 129 and 161.
Could anybody explain me how can I convert bytes array below into a char in VBA?
A working code example would be very much helpful.

```vb
Sub m1()

Dim bytes(3) As Byte
 
bytes(0) = 240
bytes(1) = 145
bytes(2) = 129
bytes(3) = 161

End Sub
```